# Can't work out why faces are wrong colour

Tags: materials, faces, color, base-color

I have an object which I have applied a single material to with a yellow base colour.  The object is definitely not yellow (see screenshot).  I can't work out why.  There are no other items or materials in the hierarchy.  I've tried searching through many settings but no luck.[image: 2]

I just can't work out what's causing it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i assume you have checked "face orientation" here:

[image]

just uncheck it

Comment: Absolutely right!  Undone by a checkbox!  Thanks.